# Using "Balance W0" in Payments & Applications screen

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to create a "Balance WO" document in Payments & Applications screen, after selecting customer when I click on save I got an error saying

> Value cannot be null

Is this is the right place to enter the "Balance WO" document? I am doing this in fresh Acumatica instance with demo data installed and without any packages published.

Acumatica 2017 R2 - Build 17.210.0034

Comment: any trace details found after the message? any field showing red indicating it needs to be filled in?

Comment: Hello Brendan, no fields are showing any warning or error, please have a look at trace here https://justpaste.it/3f52t

Comment: @John have you set up Autonumbering for Payments?

Comment: Hello Samvel, yes I did, please have a look at the screenshot and let me know if there is any mistake. Actually, I didn't make any changes to the configuration trying in standard Acumatica with demo data setup.
https://i.imgur.com/SQUfgVu.png

Comment: @John Could you please add the screenshot of the ARPayment autonumbering configuration?

Comment: Samvel, please have a look at this https://i.imgur.com/vB8YsYg.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you can't manually create Balance WO. Acumatica has separate processing page for that purpose **Write Off Balances and Credits** where you can specify the limit and generate Balance WOs
[image]
After processing the Balance WO payment will be generated:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for update Samvel, will look into it and update you.